# SVN remove/delete all externals recursively

Tags: svn

Is there a way using SVN CMD line or tortoise to remove/delete all externals recursively?   We need to start over we have many externals that were set incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you can use `propdel` with `-R` which stands for recursive.

```
svn propdel -R svn:externals
```

Comment: It is listed in `svn help propdel` in any case. So if it isn't, then my version (1.6.12) has a documentation bug.